# Why Live data not observe some value in race condition?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have some problem with my live data. when I want to set value in my live data in race condition some value not observe in my fragement. here is my detail code:

**Here Is My View Model**

```
class AuthNewViewModel(
   private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
   private val authUseCase: AuthUseCase
): ViewModel() {

   private val _sendCode = MutableLiveData<DataResult<SendCode?>>()
   val sendCode: LiveData<DataResult<SendCode?>> = _sendCode

   fun sendCode(req:CodeReq) {
       viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcher) {
           _sendCode.postValue(DataResult.Loading(true))
           authUseCase.sendCode(req)
               .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
               .catch {  error ->
                   _sendCode.postValue(error.isError())
               }
               .onCompletion {
                   _sendCode.postValue(DataResult.Loading(false))
               }
               .collect { data ->
                   when (data.meta?.code ?: 0) {
                       in 200..299 -> {
                           _sendCode.postValue(DataResult.Success(data.data))
                       }
                       else -> {
                           _sendCode.postValue(DataResult.ErrorMeta(data.data, data.errorData))
                       }
                   }
               }
       }
   }
}
```

**Here is when I want to triggred my view mode**

```
authNewVM.sendCode(
    CodeReq(
        phone = phoneOrEmail,
        channel = channel,
        type =  Constants.AuthConstants.TYPE_SIGNUP
    )
)
```

**Here is when the data is observe**

```
authNewVM.sendCode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    when(it){
        is DataResult.Success -> {
            Logs.d("result success")

        }
        is DataResult.Error -> {
            Logs.d("result error")

        }
        
        is DataResult.Loading -> {
            Logs.d("result loading ${it.isLoading}")
        }

        is DataResult.ErrorMeta -> {
            Logs.d("result error meta")
           
        }
    }
})
```

**And the result**

```
result loading true
result loading false
```

View some time not observe state success, whereas my view model is set value on succes to..

Comment: Can you post AuthUseCase class, please ?

Comment: LiveData has few limitations/"issues": (1) if two "postValue()" are called too quick only the latest one will be posted, and (2) if you are observing from two different places at the same time then "viewLifecycleOwner" should be the same for both places or LiveData will be different for both of them.

Comment: hai @emandt thank you for response, do yo have any suggestion to handle this limitation for post value?

Comment: The only solution I found was to create my custom MutableLiveData that do a real Queue, in this way all postValue() are posted and handled.

Comment: okey, thank you @emandt for the advice, it's help me a lot